# Is this operator pseudodifferential or trace-class?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, operator-theory, spin-geometry, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $M$ be a closed manifold and $D$ a Dirac operator on $M$. Then (the closure of) $D^2+1$ has a bounded inverse 
$$(D^2+1)^{-1}:L^2\rightarrow H^2,$$ 
where $H^2$ is the second Sobolev space. In fact, $(D^2+1)^{-1}$ is a compact operator on $L^2$ by Rellich's lemma.

**Question 1:** Is $(D^2+1)^{-1}$ a properly supported pseudodifferential operator if $M$ is non-compact?

**Question 2:** Is $(D^2+1)^{-1}$ a trace-class operator on $L^2$ (when $M$ is compact)?

*Thoughts:* I am not sure about the first question, but I believe the answer to the second question is no (although certainly one can raise $(D^2+1)^{-1}$ to a high enough power to get a trace-class operator), although I don't know how to show explicitly that it's not trace-class.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "properly supported"? I think the second question has a negative answer. It seems that it fails if $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ (a trace class operator is compact and a compact operator has discrete spectrum except at $0$, so any continuous-spectrum operator is excluded)